# How to use ban_error and kick_error in discord.py cogs?

Tags: python, discord

I have a discord bot and have been starting to split it up with cogs. However, there is one part which I cannot replicate. Normally, in the main py file, I have

```
@ban.error
async def ban_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(":x: You don't have permissions to ban members.")

@kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(":x: You don't have permissions to kick members.")
```

However, these two listeners do not exist in cogs. How can I replicate the same behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet works

```
    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
            await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.red(), description=f":x: You don't have the permission to execute this bot command!"))
```